# RxJava subscribeOn and observeOn not override the original Scheduler set before?

Tags: android, rx-java

I used RxJava in android with Retrofit 2 and I have invoked  subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) android observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) global before subscribe(). 
However, sometime I would like to call subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate()) android observeOn(Schedulers.immediate()) to override the Schedulers set before to get synchronized process. But I found it doesn't work, android works would be still processed on io() thread, android result processed by mainThread().
Why?

Comment: So, everything should work. It would be better if you show some code sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's just the way RxJava works.

Take a look at [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/Jt-_oVQVZlQ?t=771), starting at the 12:50 mark. So given the example in the video:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

What happens is that `subscribeOn()` nests all calls. In this case `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` is spawned first and subscribes everything above it on the io thread. But then `subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` is spawned next and it takes priority (since it was called last) to subscribe everything on it instead. There is no building a chain of threads. In this example, you are essentially spawning the io thread for no good reason.

To better handle the `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()` methods, I suggest you take a look at [this post](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/) from the same author of the video. What he is proposing is to use a `Transformer` to wrap the call to these methods:

> `Transformer` is actually just `Func1<Observable<T>, Observable<R>>`. In
>   other words: feed it an `Observable` of one type and it'll return an
>   `Observable` of another. That's exactly the same as calling a series of
>   operators inline.

This way, you can have a method like so:

```
<T> Transformer<T, T> applySchedulers() {  
    return observable -> observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Or, if you want to reuse your transformers, you can have the following setup:

```
final Transformer schedulersTransformer =  
    observable -> observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> Transformer<T, T> applySchedulers() {  
    return (Transformer<T, T>) schedulersTransformer;
}
```

Then the above example would look like:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
    .compose(applySchedulers())
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer really help me. After I reading the source code. I found Observable.just(1, 2, 3).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(System.out::println); would fork 3 threads, originalThread -> newThread -> ioThread. So finally, the prinln method would be call at ioThread which is created from newThread and newThread is created from originalThread.

Comment: Also, as a follow up to this, there's an article that Dan Lew wrote that covers this: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/