# what is better using rxjava to do "validate-then-insert" pattern in android?

Tags: android, rx-java

The user input a url from the ui,and then my presenter validate it,if it is valid,insert it into the db,else show error;
my solution looks like:

```
@Override
public void addFeed(final String uri) {
    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
            //may contain some database query,if it has,how should i do ?
            subscriber.onNext(uri.startsWith(FeedFetcher.FEED_SCHEME) && !uri.startsWith(FeedFetcher.HTTP_SCHEME));
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    }).doOnNext(new Action1<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {
            //insert into db
            if (aBoolean)
                mFeedModel.add(uri);
        }
    }).subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {
            if (aBoolean){
                mFeedInputView.hideInputError();
            }else{
              mFeedInputView.showInputError(R.string.url_format_error);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**updated **

```
if (uri.startsWith(FeedFetcher.FEED_SCHEME) ||  uri.startsWith(FeedFetcher.HTTP_SCHEME)) {
        mFeedInputView.hideInputError();
        mChannelModel.isChannelExists(uri)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(new Func1<Boolean, Observable<RssChannel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<RssChannel> call(Boolean aBoolean) {
                        if (aBoolean)
                            return mChannelModel.add(uri);
                        return Observable.empty();
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<RssChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(RssChannel channel) {
                        mFeedInputView.addUrlSuccess();
                    }
                });
    } else {
        mFeedInputView.showInputError(R.string.url_format_error);
    }
```

but i think putting if(aBoolean) in the flapmap is not a pretty solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
public void addFeed(String uri) {
    Observable.just(uri)
            .first(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(String uri) {
                    return uri.startsWith(FeedFetcher.FEED_SCHEME) && !uri.startsWith(FeedFetcher.HTTP_SCHEME);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    mFeedInputView.hideInputError();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    mFeedInputView.showInputError(R.string.url_format_error);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {
                    mFeedModel.add(uri);
                }
            });
}
```

The [`first()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html) operator will filter out invalid uris it receives based on your filter rule and throw a `NoSuchElementException` if no valid uri is found (in your case, if the one passed as parameter is invalid).

`onCompleted()` will be called only if the uri is valid so you can be safe to call `hideInputError()` there. `onError()` will be called instead of `onCompleted()` only if an error occurs so it is safe to do the error handling there. Finally, `onNext()` will be called when the uri is valid since the `first()` operator is ignoring invalid uris so it is safe to save it there.

Note that I removed the `final` attribute from your method declaration. There is no need for it here since you are passing the uri itself down the chain with `just()`.

Also worth noting that you don't have to use RxJava for the sake of it. In your case, if you don't need to run this asynchronously, this is probably a much cleaner solution:

```
public void addFeed(String uri) {
    if (uri.startsWith(FeedFetcher.FEED_SCHEME) && !uri.startsWith(FeedFetcher.HTTP_SCHEME)) {
        mFeedInputView.hideInputError();
        mFeedModel.add(uri);
    } else {
        mFeedInputView.showInputError(R.string.url_format_error);
    }
}
```

Comment: mFeedModel.add(uri) // this operation is asynchronous, so i dont think it is appropriate to put it in on next?
and the validation may be asynchronous,querying from the database..

Comment: First, don't use `observeOn()` more than once. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35673014/362298

Comment: As for your updated solution, you should try to avoid conditional statements and loops in the chain. There are operators for that like `filter()` and `first()`.

Answer (score 0):

I much rather has this code in more functional way.

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>())
          .map(b -> b = false)
          .doOnNext(uri.startsWith(FeedFetcher.FEED_SCHEME) && !uri.startsWith(FeedFetcher.HTTP_SCHEME))
          .map(b -> {
                  mFeedModel.add(uri);
                  b=true;
                  return b;
                   })
          .subscribe(b-> {
                         if(!b){
                            mFeedInputView.showInputError(R.string.url_format_error);
                           }
                          });
```